# How to make a function of arrays in node js, handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I was new to `node.js` and trying to render a list of fruits using `hbs` or handlebars in the client that came from the server

I wonder how to make a functions or event in every fruits

This is how i render the fruits

app.js

```
app.post('/getList', function(request, response) {
if (request.session.loggedin) {
        //here i am sending the arrays to the client in the homepage
        response.render('home',{fruits:fruits()});
} else {
    response.send('Please login to view this page!');
}
```

This is my home.bhs

```
<form action="getList" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" >
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
            <input type="submit" value="Insert">
        <ul>{{#each fruits}}</ul>
                    <li>{{this}}</li>//Here are the list of frutis and i want to make them clickable
            {{/each}}
</form>
});
```

This is my arrays

```
let fruits=()=>{
let list = ["apple","asdas","bbb","ccc","dddd"];
return list;
};
```

Comment: Please describe what you want more. What do you want to happen when one is clicked? Should it link to another page or call some JS?

Comment: I think he wants to make an action to request again in the server. like `app.get('/fruitname',`?